# Retrieve a list of Accounts via REST

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am using Postman to get all account records from salesforce.
The below code is working for only one record

```
@HttpGet global static Account doGet() 
    {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String AccNumber = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     Account result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account Limit 1];
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is   when I  use  the  list  in order to get all accounts record  Please  check the code  below

```
@HttpGet global static Account doGet() 
    {

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String AccNumber = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      list<Account> result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account LIMIT 2];
        return result;
    }
```

its show error ...."**`Illegal conversion from List<Account> to Account`** "
I don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a custom API class to query all Accounts. Use the out-of-the-box [SOQL Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) endpoint instead.

The specific problem in this code is that your method is declared to return one Account:

```
@HttpGet global static Account doGet()
```

but you are in fact returning a `List<Account>`, which is not the same type:

```
  list<Account> result = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account LIMIT 2];
```

While you could change the method signature to fix this by returning `List<Account>`, you should instead use the standard REST API endpoint.

Note that much of this code does nothing at all; the method reduces to

```
return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website FROM Account LIMIT 2];
```

Comment: its work David  thanks